# SQL query to get result as below

Tags: sql, pivot

```
id   name   Content
 1   abc    khsdchdcdhkj
 1   abc    kjwdfwvkkvj
 1   abc    poiwejefoefoen
 2   def    oiwejfioweocwnf
 2   def    liweenfowejnvouer
 2   def    oiewjvoivoewfoiff
 3   ghi    oljevnjoernvjeno
 3   ghi    oinrevoinewovoewfio
 3   ghi    oljewnfjewnfjwenfjef
 4   xyz    ojnwefojnweuofoioinvc
 4   xyz    kjnwefjonwefojoojn
 4   xyz    oijdofijweoifjoijiojwfvn
```

to convert as below:

Result should be this

```
id   name   Content1       Content2              Content 3
 1   abc    khsdchdcdhkj    kjwdfwvkkvj           poiwejefoefoen
 2   def    oiwejfioweocwnf liweenfowejnvouer     oiewjvoivoewfoiff
```

Comment: tried this query   
select *
from 
(
select id,name,group_concat(content)
group by id
from test
) d
 pivot
(
distinct(id)
for content in (id,name,Content)
) as piv;

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation and `row_number()`:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then content end) as content1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then content end) as content2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then content end) as content3
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by id order by content) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id
```

Note:  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So the ordering of the three columns is by `content`.  If you want another ordering, then you need to have information about the ordering you want in a column.

Answer (score 0):

You could acheive this using `GROUP_CONCAT()` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Content ORDER BY Content), ',', 1) AS Content1,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Content ORDER BY Content), ',', 2), ',', -1) AS Content2,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Content ORDER BY Content), ',', 3), ',', -1) AS Content3
FROM table_name
GROUP BY id, name;
```

If there are more than 3 values you would just add another SELECT and increment the number in the innermost `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` like: `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Content ORDER BY Content), ',', 4), ',', -1) AS Content4`